# Need suggestion to replace the thermal fuse of a heater

Tags: soldering, clamp, thermal-cutoff

I got a mal-functioned heater from a community group.  After diagnosis, I found one of the thermal fuse was blown.  I got the replacement fuse and now face the question of how to replace it.

The thermal fuse is rated at 84 deg C and clamped to the circuit board.  The board also has a diode so there must be a circuit buried inside the board.  That means I cannot just ditch the board.  Is there any better way to replace the one?

BTW, what is the name of that bushing/clamping thingy that connects the power wire on one side and the thermal fuse on the other side?   (sorry, I am a software engineer and not that familiar with the electrical terminology.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe that the *bushing/clamping* you refer to, are hollow rivets.

Comment: The thermal fuse is a safety component, it burned out for a reason, (eg. over heating). So before you just replace and reuse the device check if the fan is defective or if there could be anything restricting the air flow.

Comment: Nedd - good idea.  I will jump it and see if there is any other thing wrong.

Comment: "The board also has a diode so there must be a circuit buried inside the board" no, that's not the case. You can see very clearly that there's nothing on the board but these two devices which are directly connected to the cables. Nothing buried at all.

Comment: MiNiMe- Thanks.  Now I think I can drill it and replace it with another one.

Comment: Marcus - Hmm, it does not make sense to have a diode on this board.  There are two boards of the same type and each has a thermal fuse and a diode.  The black wires are from the control board located at the top of the heater.  The control board has plenty of room for two small diodes.

Comment: the diode is probably used as a sensor ... maybe it's not even a diode

Comment: use two thin bolts, two nuts and four washers ... cut off the fuse leads... do not remove the ends from under the rivets ... clamp the new fuse into position using the bolts

Comment: The glass-packaged component has no polarity markings that I can see, so it's probably not a diode. Maybe a thermistor or a silicon temperature dependent resistor. Of course if you try to solder an 84°C thermal fuse you'll likely destroy it unless your heat sinking of the leads is extraordinarily good (which is why they used the method they used). Maybe a terminal strip would be better, in any case it would be better to use crimped or pressure connections.

Comment: Nothing against the suggestions that have been given out, but if you use a homemade solder-less method of attaching the replacement thermal fuse, you are creating a secondary fire risk from an intermittent connection. The thermal fuse might protect against this, but it also might not since the original use case didn't. I applaud the intention but since this is a safety device on heat producing equipment that could be used in an occupied dwelling with perhaps sleeping inhabitants and has already activated once (possibly because something else inside is broken), I recommend buying a new heater.